# Flexbox in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

I'm trying to get flex box working in IE10 but it's not working. Safari, Chrome and Firefox are working fine, but IE10 doesn't wanna work. Anyone knows the answer?

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vcEGH/

```
  display: -moz-box;              /* OLD - Firefox 19- (doesn't work very well) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;           /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;          /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;

  -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
  -moz-box-lines: multiple;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: can you provide a codepen or fiddle ?

Comment: Also, please expand on what is not working: is it completely ignoring the styles, or just not laying out how you want / expect? Be specific.

Comment: caniuse.com : _In IE10 and IE11, containers with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has `min-height` but no explicit `height` property. [See bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview)._

Comment: I'm doing this for a blogger layout, but the general idea is like this:

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vcEGH/

Comment: set a `width:100%;` to `.label-size-container` , it is a known bug

Comment: @GCyrillus that's not working. The words aren't spread, just next to each other without any space

Comment: okay, last option, child of flex box should not be inline, reset display to inline-block or else , but inline

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For IE10 , span should be displayed as `inline-block` to trigger layout somehow .

---

Test here if it fixes it : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/lhsEt

Comment: Nothing's changing in IE10

Comment: @user3071261 okay, so it has to do with the spans , set them as : `span{display:inline-block;}` to trigger layout

Comment: IE10 > still fussing around about layout :)!,  you are welcome.

Comment: Thanks, display: block or inline-block + flex-shrink: 1; Worked like a charm :)

Comment: This still seems to be the case. Any idea why?