# How do you center a container inside of a column?

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

[image]

I can't figure out how to center my image containers inside of my columns. Also for some reason the middle picture does not display even though everything is set up exactly how the other two are, is there some reason this is occurring?

Also, for whatever reason my columns do not format correctly when using google chrome. I thought the -webkit- was suppose to fix this?

```css
.columns {
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 column-count: 3;
 column-gap: 20px;
}

.columns-format {
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;
}

.image-container {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 margin: auto;
}

.image-container hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
```

```html
<div class="columns">
<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Professionals</h4>
<p>As Northeast Ohio Landscapers, Landscaping Company has been caring for customers and their properties throughout Cuyahoga County since 1981.</p>

<p>Our core values:
<ul>
 <li>Bring a positive attitude with you each and every day</li>
 <li>Work hard, pitch in, be helpful and productive</li>
 <li>Be fair and respectful with all people in all encounters</li>
</ul>
</p>
<div class="image-container">
 <a target="_blank" href="images/stairwell.jpg">
  <img src="images/stairwell.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Services</h4>
<p>Whether you are new to Cuyahoga County, switching landscape service providers, or need to add a service to your existing account, Landscaping Company makes it easy for you.</p>
<p>Experienced in every facet of the landscape industry, we fulfil our one goal - total care philosophy by meeting your every need in the following areas:</p>
<p>Residential Landscape</p>
<p>Maintenance Landscape</p>
<p>Design/Installation</p>
<p>Plant Health Care</p>
<div class="image-container">
 <a target="_blank" href="images/flowers.jpg">
  <img src="images/flowers.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Mission</h4>
<p>When it comes to Residential Landscape Maintenance in Northeast Ohio, we have a pretty simple mission.</p>
<p>Our mission is to unite people in positive relationships to improve lives.</p>
<p>This includes not only our great customers but also our fantastic employees and vendors that we work with each and every day.</p>
<p>If we are not improving your life then we are not living up to our mission.</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
 <a target="_blank" href="images/lighting.jpg">
  <img src="images/lighting.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: prepare a fiddle?  it ishard to deal with snippets

Comment: @Siddharth https://jsfiddle.net/babws8k3/ I noticed that snippets are bad unless you expand it to full screen. It also looks weird in Google Chrome for whatever reason so if you use IE or FireFox it will look better. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: got it, added an answer, have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you use `flexbox` instead of `columns`.

`columns` is more meant to make texts and images to dynamically spread over a certain amount of columns and your sample looks more as 3 columns that should have its content contained within each column, which `columns` does not do.

To make your images/columns not overlap, you either give the `columns-format` a minimum width (in below sample), set the image size to percent, wrap the columns, etc.

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.columns-format {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.image-container {
  text-align: center;
}
.image-container a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.image-container a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="columns-format">
    <h4>Professionals</h4>
    <p>As Northeast Ohio Landscapers, Landscaping Company has been caring for customers and their properties throughout Cuyahoga County since 1981.</p>

    <p>Our core values:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Bring a positive attitude with you each and every day</li>
      <li>Work hard, pitch in, be helpful and productive</li>
      <li>Be fair and respectful with all people in all encounters</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="image-container">
      <a target="_blank" href="images/stairwell.jpg">
        <img src="images/stairwell.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columns-format">
    <h4>Services</h4>
    <p>Whether you are new to Cuyahoga County, switching landscape service providers, or need to add a service to your existing account, Landscaping Company makes it easy for you.</p>
    <p>Experienced in every facet of the landscape industry, we fulfil our one goal - total care philosophy by meeting your every need in the following areas:</p>
    <p>Residential Landscape</p>
    <p>Maintenance Landscape</p>
    <p>Design/Installation</p>
    <p>Plant Health Care</p>
    <div class="image-container">
      <a target="_blank" href="images/flowers.jpg">
        <img src="images/flowers.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="columns-format">
    <h4>Mission</h4>
    <p>When it comes to Residential Landscape Maintenance in Northeast Ohio, we have a pretty simple mission.</p>
    <p>Our mission is to unite people in positive relationships to improve lives.</p>
    <p>This includes not only our great customers but also our fantastic employees and vendors that we work with each and every day.</p>
    <p>If we are not improving your life then we are not living up to our mission.</p>
    <div class="image-container">
      <a target="_blank" href="images/lighting.jpg">
        <img src="images/lighting.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, except it keeps formatting it so the bottom of the columns are aligned which leaves a bunch of white space in the first and third column. Not sure how to fix this. http://imgur.com/a/71tQi Looks like it only occurs in IE, works in Google Chrome, however when I resize it in Google Chrome it overlaps the container instead of being responsive. http://imgur.com/a/ySHZI

Comment: @ChaCol In your screen dump it looks like the `column` has `align-items: flex-end;`, should be `align-items: flex-start;`. To be sure what does this, I need to see the code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kjtqybuu/ I just used the code you gave me. What does the justify-content: space-between do? It doesn't seem like it is reconizing it.

Comment: @ChaCol Updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/kjtqybuu/1/, where `container1` got a `min-width` so the columns won't overlap. For IE 10 you need to prefix `flex` properties, IE 11 works fine for me

Comment: @ChaCol The `space-between` makes the 10% gap to be between the columns (3 times 30% column = 90%, 10% left)

Comment: I can just add display: -ms-flex; under .columns and it should fix it right? For some reason it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125227/discussion-between-chacol-and-lgson).

Comment: `display: -ms-flexbox; -ms-flex-pack: justify;` ... see more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031813/flexbox-in-ie10

Comment: That seemed to fix it. I didn't have flexbox, I just had flex.

Answer (score 1):

Add another class in section -

```
<div class="columns-format">
<div class='text-container'>
<h4>Professionals</h4>
<p>As Northeast Ohio Landscapers, Landscaping Company has been caring for customers and their properties throughout Cuyahoga County since 1981.</p>

<p>Our core values:
<ul>
    <li>Bring a positive attitude with you each and every day</li>
    <li>Work hard, pitch in, be helpful and productive</li>
    <li>Be fair and respectful with all people in all encounters</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/stairwell.jpg">
        <img src="images/stairwell.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
        </a>
</div>
</div>
```

and put css

```
.text-container{text-align: left;}
```

add two line in css of columns-format

```
.columns-format {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the most part. For some reason it formatted my sections to not be in separate columns anymore. Do you know how I can fix that? http://imgur.com/a/S2Rxm

Comment: You can use <table> or for better output i will recommend to use bootstrap row and column that would work on responsive website also.

Answer (score 0):

Is this output R u expecting?

check the output in [Link to Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wuruxorido/edit?html,css)

```css
.columns {
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 column-count: 3;
 column-gap: 20px;
}

.columns-format {
   text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
 
 
}

.image-container {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.image-container hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="columns">
<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Professionals</h4>
<p>As Northeast Ohio Landscapers, Landscaping Company has been caring for customers and their properties throughout Cuyahoga County since 1981.</p>

<p>Our core values:
<ul>
 <li>Bring a positive attitude with you each and every day</li>
 <li>Work hard, pitch in, be helpful and productive</li>
 <li>Be fair and respectful with all people in all encounters</li>
</ul>
</p>
<div class="image-container">
 <a target="_blank" href="images/stairwell.jpg">
  <img src="images/stairwell.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Services</h4>
<p>Whether you are new to Cuyahoga County, switching landscape service providers, or need to add a service to your existing account, Landscaping Company makes it easy for you.</p>
<p>Experienced in every facet of the landscape industry, we fulfil our one goal - total care philosophy by meeting your every need in the following areas:</p>
<p>Residential Landscape</p>
<p>Maintenance Landscape</p>
<p>Design/Installation</p>
<p>Plant Health Care</p>
<div class="image-container">
 <a target="_blank" href="images/flowers.jpg">
  <img src="images/flowers.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Mission</h4>
<p>When it comes to Residential Landscape Maintenance in Northeast Ohio, we have a pretty simple mission.</p>
<p>Our mission is to unite people in positive relationships to improve lives.</p>
<p>This includes not only our great customers but also our fantastic employees and vendors that we work with each and every day.</p>
<p>If we are not improving your life then we are not living up to our mission.</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
 <a target="_blank" href="images/lighting.jpg">
  <img src="images/lighting.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
  </a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just the image containers at the bottom, not the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need a surrounding div around before your inline-block image container. Something like adding the class

`.centered{
  text-align:center
  }`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  .columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
  }

  .columns-format {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
  }

  .image-container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 5px;
      transition: 0.3s;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .image-container hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
  }
  .centered{
    text-align:center;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="columns">
<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Professionals</h4>
<p>As Northeast Ohio Landscapers, Landscaping Company has been caring for customers and their properties throughout Cuyahoga County since 1981.</p>

<p>Our core values:
<ul>
    <li>Bring a positive attitude with you each and every day</li>
    <li>Work hard, pitch in, be helpful and productive</li>
    <li>Be fair and respectful with all people in all encounters</li>
</ul>
</p>
<div class = "centered">

<div class="image-container">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/stairwell.jpg">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="250px" height="200px">
        </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Services</h4>
<p>Whether you are new to Cuyahoga County, switching landscape service providers, or need to add a service to your existing account, Landscaping Company makes it easy for you.</p>
<p>Experienced in every facet of the landscape industry, we fulfil our one goal - total care philosophy by meeting your every need in the following areas:</p>
<p>Residential Landscape</p>
<p>Maintenance Landscape</p>
<p>Design/Installation</p>
<p>Plant Health Care</p>

<div class = "centered">
<div class="image-container">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/flowers.jpg">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="250px" height="200px">
        </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Mission</h4>
<p>When it comes to Residential Landscape Maintenance in Northeast Ohio, we have a pretty simple mission.</p>
<p>Our mission is to unite people in positive relationships to improve lives.</p>
<p>This includes not only our great customers but also our fantastic employees and vendors that we work with each and every day.</p>
<p>If we are not improving your life then we are not living up to our mission.</p>
</div>

<div class = "centered">

<div class="image-container">
    <a target="_blank" href="images/lighting.jpg">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" width="250px" height="200px">
        </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might work as well. Do you know why in Google Chrome it distorts the columns as if only 2 instead of 3? http://imgur.com/a/I5PUE

Answer (score 0):

just add `display: flex` to `.column-formats` and give `flex-direction` `column` and you are good to go

```css
.columns {
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 column-count: 3;
 column-gap: 20px;
}

.columns-format {
 display: flex;
 width: auto;
    flex-direction:column
}

.image-container {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 margin: auto;
}

.image-container hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
```

```html
<div class="columns">
<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Professionals</h4>
<p>As Northeast Ohio Landscapers, Landscaping Company has been caring for customers and their properties throughout Cuyahoga County since 1981.</p>

<p>Our core values:
<ul>
 <li>Bring a positive attitude with you each and every day</li>
 <li>Work hard, pitch in, be helpful and productive</li>
 <li>Be fair and respectful with all people in all encounters</li>
</ul>
</p>
<div class="image-container">
 <a target="_blank" href="images/stairwell.jpg">
  <img src="images/stairwell.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Services</h4>
<p>Whether you are new to Cuyahoga County, switching landscape service providers, or need to add a service to your existing account, Landscaping Company makes it easy for you.</p>
<p>Experienced in every facet of the landscape industry, we fulfil our one goal - total care philosophy by meeting your every need in the following areas:</p>
<p>Residential Landscape</p>
<p>Maintenance Landscape</p>
<p>Design/Installation</p>
<p>Plant Health Care</p>
<div class="image-container">
 <a target="_blank" href="images/flowers.jpg">
  <img src="images/flowers.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
  </a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="columns-format">
<h4>Mission</h4>
<p>When it comes to Residential Landscape Maintenance in Northeast Ohio, we have a pretty simple mission.</p>
<p>Our mission is to unite people in positive relationships to improve lives.</p>
<p>This includes not only our great customers but also our fantastic employees and vendors that we work with each and every day.</p>
<p>If we are not improving your life then we are not living up to our mission.</p>
<div class="image-container">
 <a target="_blank" href="images/lighting.jpg">
  <img src="images/lighting.jpg" width="250px" height="200px">
  </a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```